# Vector push back function in structure not working

Tags: c++, vector, structure

I want to store a vector in a structure and then append to the vector from a function. Does this even make sense or can I only create elements in my vector when creating it? If no, where is the error in the code below, because if I execute it, it simply prints nothing. I want it to store the numbers 0-4 as components of the vector nums in holder.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"

using namespace std;

struct layers{
    vector<float> nums;
};

void range(layers layer){
    for(int n = 0; n< 5; n++){
        layer.nums.push_back(n);
    }
}

int main(){
    layers holder;
    range(holder);
    for(int k  = 0; k < holder.nums.size(); k++){
        std::cout << holder.nums[k] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want a reference: `void range(layers& layer){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the `layer` parameter by reference, not by value. Instead of `void range(layers layer)`, do `void range(layers &layer)`.

If you pass by value, you are making a copy of the vector and then modify this copy inside the function, so your original vector remains untouched. If you pass by reference, the original vector is modified.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDNasMwEITv@xSLAkUmJPTSS@z2RUopqrxJhOWV0U@gLX52V7YUSvagw@x8O4P0NB20VXxZlp1hbVNPKIwL0ZMaBfxrN9LReQGQguELshopTEoThti3ABlIOqJV3@TDL2CeQnRn61R8Q05jaGHO1pszPfocSbLY8alwTeHOzkvDERlf8blF7vAlv/t9Xa@z2Y/ryeOUwvXzS@lBctNuhhlmgPXAqAzLStWkq7M9@eIrFYpS0Xv0gCV7wK4iJSyYH5JN1h/a5B84nbRLEbsH@/vwsSoCxb3YFksxec7XYV6WPw)

```cpp
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"

using namespace std;

struct layers{
    vector<float> nums;
};

void range(layers & layer){
    for(int n = 0; n< 5; n++){
        layer.nums.push_back(n);
    }
}

int main(){
    layers holder;
    range(holder);
    for(int k  = 0; k < holder.nums.size(); k++){
        std::cout << holder.nums[k] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
```